# store form info in jinja framework

Tags: html, web, flask, web-applications, jinja2

I am developing a product recommendation system in python flask framework.

Right now this display_recommendations.html will display the "best" 10 products that are being selected from the database by the algorithm. after the user makes the choice by checking checkboxes in the html form, I wish I can store a variable in this html template and then pass it along to submit_choices(), which is the event handler when the user clicks "Submit my choices and Play Another Round!" button

The submit_choices() function will then do the updating of database(adjust confidence scores, update user preferences, etc)

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}
<h1> Welcome {{session.username}}! </h1>
<h4>You can select the pillows you like and the ones you don't, after that, hit submit, or return to dashboard</h4>
<hr>
<form action="" method="post">
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Image</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>

</tr>
{% set likes = '100' %}
<!-- {% set nopes = [] %} -->
{% for pic in pictures %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{pic.idx}}</td>
    <td>{{pic.price}}</td>
    <td><img src = {{pic.img}} width = "350"></td>

    <td>
      <!-- <form action="" method="post"> -->
        <input type="checkbox" id="like" class="btn btn-success" name = "like" class="form-control" value= {{pic.idx}}>
        <label for="like">I like it!</label>
      <!-- </form> -->
    </td>


    <td>
      <!-- <form action="" method="post"> -->
        <input type="checkbox" id="nope" class="btn btn-danger"  name = "nope" class="form-control" value={{pic.idx}}>
        <label for="nope">Nope</label>
      <!-- </form> -->
    </td>


  </tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
</form>

<form action="{{url_for('submit_choices',choices= [likes,nopes])}}">
<input type="submit" value="Submit my choices and Play Another Round!" class="btn btn-danger">

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "store a variable in this html template"? You want the form data to be submitted to the submit_choices() event handler? You need to put the checkboxes and the submit button in 1 form instead of 3 like you had it, and just the button in the form like you have it now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the checkboxes and submit button all in 1 form:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"> 
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to do what @lciamp said.  And for the Jinja2 part, I would replace `<form action="{{url_for('submit_choices',choices= [likes,nopes])}}">` with `<form action="https://[rest of URL]/[abc]" method="post">`.

`<label for="like">I like it!</label>` needs to be changed, `like` can only be used for one(they have to be unique because that's how the server checks what each field is).

Then, assuming `submit_choices()` is in Python on the server, you should add a `@app.route` decorator.

Example(`[abc]` is what you wrote at the top):

```
@app.route('/[abc]', methods=['POST'])
def submit_choices():
    #Whatever you put here
    #To access the form data use:
    request.values.get('[whatever comes after the "for" in the label]')
```

If you have any questions, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data).

Hope I helped.